# Google Apps Script - Problems with Creating Calendar Event from spreadsheet to non-default calendars

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

I created a script earlier this year to create a calendar event from a spreadsheet line, putting it onto a shared family calendar and a secondary calendar of my own.

It was running fine earlier this year, but now instead of adding to the secondary calendars, it only adds to my default calendar, which I don't have coded into the script at all.

Did something change with the syntax of how to call a calendar by ID?

```
//push new events to calendar
function pushToCalendar() {

  //spreadsheet variables
  var book = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var now = new Date();
  var currentYear = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(now.getTime()), 'America/Chicago', 'yyyy');
  var currentSheet = ("Events" + " " + currentYear);
  var sheet = book.getSheetByName(currentSheet);
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow(); 
  var lastCol = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var range = sheet.getRange(2,1,lastRow,lastCol);
  var values = range.getValues();

      //calendar variables
      var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('sample1@group.calendar.google.com');
      var calendarShared = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('sample2@group.calendar.google.com');

      var numValues = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {     
        //check to see if values 0,1,3,4,5,6 are filled out
      if ((values[i][0]) && (values[i][1]) && (values[i][3]) && (values[i][4]) && (values[i][5]) && (values[i][6])) 
      {

          //check if it's been entered before  (values[i][8] = '')||(values[i][8] = null)  
          if (values[i][7].toString().toLowerCase() !== 'y') { 

            //create event https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_calendarapp#createEvent
            var newEventTitle = 'Game: ' + values[i][0] + ' - ' + values[i][1];
            var newSharedTitle = 'Adam - Game: ' + values[i][0] + ' - ' + values[i][1];
            var startDay = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(values[i][3]), 'America/Chicago', 'MMMM dd, yyyy');
            var startTime = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(values[i][4]), 'America/Chicago', 'HH:mm');
            var start = startDay + ' ' + startTime;
            var endDay = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(values[i][5]), 'America/Chicago', 'MMMM dd, yyyy');
            var endTime = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(values[i][6]), 'America/Chicago', 'HH:mm');
            var end = endDay+ ' ' + endTime;
            var details = values[i][9] + ' - $' + values[i][10] + '\n' + '\n' + 'Crew: ' + '\n' + values[i][14] + '\n' + values[i][15] + '\n' + values[i][16] + '\n' + '\n' +'Assessor:' + '\n' + values[i][17];

            //new event on Secondary AND Shared Calendar
            var newEvent = calendar.createEvent(newEventTitle, new Date(start), new Date(end), {location: values[i][13], description: details});
            var newSharedEvent = calendarShared.createEvent(newSharedTitle, new Date(start), new Date(end), {location: values[i][13], description: details});
            //get ID
            var newEventId = newEvent.getId();

            //mark as entered, enter ID
            sheet.getRange(i+2,8).setValue('y');
            sheet.getRange(i+2,9).setValue(newEventId);

          } 
        else;
        }

        numValues++;
      }
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: If you want to know the current implementation, maybe you can check the [documentation from apps script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-app#getCalendarById(String)) on how to call the calendar using ID. Upon checking it is still the same "`var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('en.usa#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com');`". Also, try to check as well if

Answer (score 0):

Try to create the event and after insert it into your calendar like this:

```
 var event = {
summary:summary,
location: location,
description: '',
start: {dateTime: newdatestart.toISOString()},
end: {dateTime: newdateend.toISOString()},
attendees: [
{email: ''},{email: ''}],
// Red background. Use Calendar.Colors.get() for the full list.
colorId: 11
};

event = Calendar.Events.insert(event, calendarId);
```

Comment: What difference is this going to make? It's not the event creation part that is failing, it's the part where it gets directed to the wrong calendar.

Comment: When you run your script in debug do you have the correct ID for your calendars? If you actually get the correct one it seems that it is the way you add the event in it which is failling that is why I advise you in that case to try this method to add it : event= calendars.events.insert(event, 'yourcalendarid') it may resolve your problem as the calendar API evolved during the year. The way you get the id of your calendar is correct.

Comment: I was able to fix it all. The code above still works. I had mistakenly copied some these functions deep into another .gs file in the same project, prior to the version where the events copy to the secondary calendars. Looks like the deep copies were running instead of the recently edited ones. Quite the lesson in version control for me!

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this same problem with ID as well....apparently you need to get rid of @google.com part of the Event ID itself, and then get it as part of an array

```
.getId().split('@')[0];
```

just add this code and it worked like a charm for me